# One word string made into a list of the letters

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of words but I need to take the last item off the list, perform a function with the rest of the list then replace the last item. But for some reason when i go to to replace the last item, it does this...

```
>>> List = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list']
>>> last = List[-1]
>>> others = List[:-1]
>>> others += last
>>> print others
['this', 'is', 'a', 'l', 'i', 's', 't']
```

Is there any way I can concatenate the list called last onto others but have it just one single element.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `append`

`others.append(last)`

You can further simplify the code by doing this:

```
last = List.pop()
```

This removes the last element or `List` if no parameter is specified, and saves it in the variable `last` for you

Answer (score 2):

Use append instead of +=:

```
>>> others.append(last)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use:**

```
others.append(last)
```

instead of

```
others += last
```

**This is because**:

When you are doing

```
list += ["somethingHere"]
```

it's equivalent to

```
list.extend(["somethingHere"])
```

**According to the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html),**

> list.extend(L) =  Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list

but

> list.append(x) = Add an item to the end of the list

And what you need here is to " add **an** item " not to " append **all** the items in the given list " *(all characters in this case.)*

Answer (score 0):

Please use one following:

```
others += [last]
others.append(last)
```

`+` for `list` instances is iterating over element being added to it, thus iterating over string you get list of characters.

```
others += 'string'
others += ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```